# Have every control on android phone for company

Tags: android, firmware

Is it possible to have some controls on a mobile phone. ( Working for a company )
I want to do something like:

- Disable access to parameter
- Disable call
- Disable play store
- Disable message
- ...
- Enable only my application for my company

I thaught that I could made my own system, but it's seems to take so much time. So if someone has an idea. Thanks

Comment: There is [Android Enterprise](https://www.android.com/enterprise/) but I don't have enough experience to tell whether it will meet your needs. In any case, Android is open source, so you can build your own with the features that you need.

Comment: Yes there are tools for that which use Android Enterprise APIs in order to allow such control. Search for Mobile Device Management.